# way to store 32 bit value into upper half of 64 bits memory variable

Tags: assembly, x86, bit

is there a way to store 32 bit value into upper half of a 64 bits memory variable, how should this work using indirect addressing or direct addressing

like fr example if I have a variable define as

```
var1 QWORD 0
```

and my eax value is `ffffffffh`

how can i store eax value in to upper half of var1 ?

also how can i store the lower half of the same variable into 32 bits register ?

```
mov DWORD PTR [var1+3], ebx
```

didn't work

thank in advance

Comment: would this be correct `mov DWORD PTR var1, eax` ?

Answer (score 0):

this work for me:

```
mov DWORD PTR var1, eax
```